# Why am I having memory issues with flutter ChangeNotifierProvider?

Tags: flutter, dart, memory-leaks, cart, provider

I am making a shopping cart app in flutter with Change Notifier Provider. It is working fast and well at first. But it takes the more memory, the more I use it. I am adding and removing clearing items from list. Nothing complicated. Cannot know why it is working like this. It is slowing down gradually. This is main.dart:

```
class Main extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => Cart(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: swatchColor,
          primaryColor: primaryColor,
          accentColor: tertiaryColor,
          textSelectionTheme: TextSelectionThemeData(
            cursorColor: Colors.black,
            selectionColor: primaryColor,
            selectionHandleColor: primaryColor,
          ),
        ),
        initialRoute: '/login',
        routes: {
          '/home': (context) => Home(),
          '/login': (context) => Login(),
          '/tableReview': (context) => TableReview(),
          '/createOrder': (context) => CreateOrder(),
          '/orderReview': (context) => OrderReview(),
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is main cart_model.dart

```
import 'package:counter/data/models/cart_item.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class Cart extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<Item> cart = [];

  addItemToCart({@required item}) {
    Item newItem = Item(
      id: item.id,
      price: item.price is int ? item.price : int.parse(item.price),
      title: item.title,
    );
    int i = cart.indexWhere((previousItem) => previousItem.id == newItem.id);

    if (i > -1) {
      cart[i].count++;
    } else {
      cart.add(newItem);
    }

    notifyListeners();
  }

  removeItemFromCart({@required item}) {
    int index = cart.indexWhere((element) => element.id == item.id);

    if (index > -1) {
      if (cart[index].count > 1) {
        cart[index].count--;
      } else {
        cart.removeWhere((element) => element.id == item.id);
      }
    }

    notifyListeners();
  }

  clearCart() {
    cart.clear();

    notifyListeners();
  }

  int get totalPrice =>
      cart.fold(0, (total, current) => total + (current.price * current.count));
}
```

This is menuitem.dart

```
class MenuItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final dynamic foodItem;

  MenuItem({@required this.foodItem});

  void _showSecondPage(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (ctx) => Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black45,
          body: Center(
            child: Hero(
              tag: foodItem.imgPath,
              child: Image(image: NetworkImage(base_url + foodItem.imgPath)),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int itemIndex = Provider.of<Cart>(context, listen: false)
        .cart
        .indexWhere((item) => item.id == foodItem.id);

    return Container(
      height: 80,
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () => _showSecondPage(context),
                child: Hero(
                  tag: foodItem.imgPath,
                  child: CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundImage: NetworkImage(base_url + foodItem.imgPath),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 15,
              ),
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    foodItem.title,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                      fontSize: 17,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text('${foodItem.price.toString()} сум'),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
          Container(
            width: 160,
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                IconButton(
                  icon:
                      Icon(Icons.remove, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Provider.of<Cart>(context, listen: false)
                        .addItemToCart(item: foodItem);
                  },
                ),
                Text(
                  itemIndex > -1
                      ? '${Provider.of<Cart>(context).cart[itemIndex].count}'
                      : '0',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                ),
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.add, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Provider.of<Cart>(context, listen: false)
                        .addItemToCart(item: foodItem);
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is consumer part:

```
import 'package:counter/common/socketio.dart';
import 'package:counter/data/models/cart_model.dart';
import 'package:counter/presentation/widgets/empty_cart.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class OrderReview extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _OrderReviewState createState() => _OrderReviewState();
}

class _OrderReviewState extends State<OrderReview> {
  bool isCommentEnabled = false;
  String guestCount;
  String comment = '';

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final myCart = context.watch<Cart>();

    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Проверка заказа'),
      ),
      body: Builder(
        builder: (context) {
          if (myCart.cart.length > 0) {
            handleOrderCreate() async {
              SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
              String userId = prefs.getString('userId');
              String tableNum = prefs.getString('tableNum');
              String status = 'accepted';

              print('$userId, $tableNum, $status');
              Map orderToCreate = {
                'tableNum': tableNum,
                'status': 'accepted',
                'userId': userId,
                'guestCount': guestCount,
                'comment': comment,
                'foodList': myCart.cart
              };
              socketIO.emit('createOrder', json.encode(orderToCreate));
              Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/home');
              Provider.of<Cart>(context, listen: false).clearCart();
            }

            return GestureDetector(
              onTap: () => FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode()),
              child: LayoutBuilder(
                builder:
                    (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints viewportConstraints) {
                  return SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: ConstrainedBox(
                      constraints: BoxConstraints(
                        minHeight: viewportConstraints.maxHeight,
                      ),
                      child: IntrinsicHeight(
                        child: Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              horizontal: 8.0, vertical: 8.0),
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              Form(
                                key: _formKey,
                                child: Column(
                                  children: [
                                    Container(
                                      height: 350,
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                              topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                                              topRight: Radius.circular(10),
                                              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                                              bottomRight: Radius.circular(10)),
                                          boxShadow: [
                                            BoxShadow(
                                              color:
                                                  Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                                              spreadRadius: 5,
                                              blurRadius: 7,
                                              offset: Offset(0,
                                                  3), // changes position of shadow
                                            ),
                                          ]),
                                      child: ListView.separated(
                                        itemBuilder:
                                            (BuildContext context, int i) {
                                          return ListTile(
                                            title: Text(myCart.cart[i].title),
                                            trailing: Container(
                                              width: 160,
                                              child: Row(
                                                crossAxisAlignment:
                                                    CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                                    MainAxisAlignment
                                                        .spaceBetween,
                                                children: <Widget>[
                                                  IconButton(
                                                    icon: Icon(
                                                      Icons.remove,
                                                      color: Theme.of(context)
                                                          .primaryColor,
                                                    ),
                                                    onPressed: () {
                                                      Provider.of<Cart>(context,
                                                              listen: false)
                                                          .removeItemFromCart(
                                                              item: myCart
                                                                  .cart[i]);
                                                    },
                                                  ),
                                                  Text(
                                                    '${myCart.cart[i].count}',
                                                    style:
                                                        TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                                                  ),
                                                  IconButton(
                                                    icon: Icon(
                                                      Icons.add,
                                                      color: Theme.of(context)
                                                          .primaryColor,
                                                    ),
                                                    onPressed: () {
                                                      Provider.of<Cart>(context,
                                                              listen: false)
                                                          .addItemToCart(
                                                              item: myCart
                                                                  .cart[i]);
                                                    },
                                                  ),
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          );
                                        },
                                        separatorBuilder:
                                            (BuildContext context, int) {
                                          return Divider(
                                            height: 2,
                                            color: Colors.grey,
                                          );
                                        },
                                        itemCount: myCart.cart.length,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(height: 20),
                                    Container(
                                      child: TextFormField(
                                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                                          hintText: 'Количество гостей',
                                        ),
                                        onChanged: (newValue) {
                                          setState(() => guestCount = newValue);
                                        },
                                        validator: (value) {
                                          if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                                            return 'Пожалуйста, введите количество гостей!';
                                          }
                                          return null;
                                        },
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(height: 20),
                                    Container(
                                      child: TextFormField(
                                        onChanged: (newValue) {
                                          setState(() => comment = newValue);
                                        },
                                        enabled: isCommentEnabled,
                                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                                          hintText:
                                              'Лаваш острый, хот дог без майонеза и т.д.',
                                          // labelText: 'Комментарий',
                                        ),
                                        maxLines: 2,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Row(
                                      children: [
                                        Text('Комментарий'),
                                        Switch(
                                          value: isCommentEnabled,
                                          onChanged: (bool value) {
                                            setState(() =>
                                                this.isCommentEnabled = value);
                                          },
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 20),
                              Row(
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                    'Общая цена: ',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 20,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(width: 20),
                                  Text(
                                    '${myCart.totalPrice} сум',
                                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              Container(
                                height: 50,
                                width: 170,
                                child: ElevatedButton(
                                  style: ButtonStyle(
                                    backgroundColor:
                                        MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(
                                            (states) =>
                                                Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                                      handleOrderCreate();
                                    }
                                  },
                                  child: Text(
                                    'Отправить',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            );
          } else {
            print('111');
            return EmptyCart();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: May I know the `Consumer` of the `Cart` provider?

Comment: i am accessing items list with final  ```myCart = context.watch<Cart>();```

Comment: I tried consumer first. Then changed it to the above but nothing changed

Comment: Can you also add the codes for that? I just want to check how it is structured.

Comment: Hello @SardorekAminjonov what do you mean by "slowing down"? After how much time? What actions are you doing?

Comment: I have added consumer part

Comment: When I say it slows down, I have a list of items. every time i increment or decrement item count the count is also changed in the UI as I am calling ```notifyListeners()```. When the app is first launched, it is updating count without issues. But when I create new product by posting data to the server, I am clearing the cart list by calling ```cart.clear();```. After that I am trying to post another product and push items to the list. Which is becoming slower and slower as I keep adding and removing items to the list.